# Why am I seeing colors rendered differently in chrome vs IE?

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, internet-explorer, colors

The screenshots bellow were taken from Chrome 62.0.3202.94 and Internet Explorer 11.0.48 running on windows 10. Why are the blues on IE considerably more saturated than on Chrome? I have also compared MS Edge and Chrome running on Ubuntu in virtual machine and they both match the colors I see on Internet explorer. I would have though for solid blocks of colors like this, there isn't too much scope for interpretation.

[image]

Comment: About web browsers [color management](https://www.color-management-guide.com/web-browser-color-management.html)

Comment: Sorry, missed that the top bar is different as well .- incorrectly looked only at the image

Answer (score 4):

I found a solution - I went to chrome://flags and set Force Color Profile to sRGB.